# How to Highlight a string the was found using Windows C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I've created the following search function in my Windows C++ program

```
void SearchText(std::string searchString, TCHAR text[_MAX_PATH], std::string searchFor)
{
    std::size_t found;

    searchForx = const_cast<char*>(searchFor.c_str());

    found = searchString.find(searchFor);
    if (found != std::string::npos) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, searchForx, "string found", MB_OK);
    }
    if (found == std::string::npos) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, searchForx, "no string found", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

Please help me to highlight the text it found.
I know the it'll return the position of the found text as size_t found. But how to use

```
hDc = GetDC(hWnd);
SetBkMode (hDC, OPAGUE);
SetBkColor (hDC, RGB (0,255,0));
SetTextColor (hDC, RGB(255,0,255));
TextOut (hDC,10,10, cBuf, strLen (cBuf));
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
```

In Text out it's asking for X and Y coordinates but the search function returns only X, position of the 1st starting character of the returned string.

Thanks

Comment: unrelated, but here's a pro-tip. Pass your strings as `const std::string& searchString` to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Comment: Odd, that you're calling out the `std::string` here, and not even mention the **array** being passed by value. A `TCHAR` array, of all things. That's the type of code you will want to address if correctness is a goal.

Comment: @IInspectable - My crusade against TCHAR is [well documented](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A104458+tchar) on this board.

Comment: The `const_cast` is completely unnecessary in this code

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DrawTextA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtexta) with the DT_CALCRECT flag to compute the render size of the strings before you paint them. Then you can apply those coordinates transformations to your TextOut function calls.

Below is a sample WM_PAINT handler that searches a string for a particular substring and paints the found text in red.

Example:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        std::string str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the red dog";
        std::string toFind = "red";
        std::string pre = str;
        std::string found;
        std::string post;

        size_t pos = str.find(toFind, 0);

        if (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            pre = str.substr(0, pos);
            found = str.substr(pos, toFind.size());
            post = str.substr(pos + toFind.size());
        }

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        int x = 10;
        int y = 10;

        // calculate the sizes of each sub string
        RECT rectPre = {};
        RECT rectFound = {};
        DrawTextA(hdc, pre.c_str(), -1, &rectPre, DT_CALCRECT);
        DrawTextA(hdc, found.c_str(), -1, &rectFound, DT_CALCRECT);

        // draw everything before the found text
        TextOutA(hdc, x, y, pre.c_str(), pre.size());
        x += rectPre.right;

        // draw the highlighted text
        auto oldColor = SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(200, 0, 0));
        TextOutA(hdc, x, y, found.c_str(), found.size());
        x += rectFound.right;
        SetTextColor(hdc, oldColor);

        // draw the remaining text after the highlighted portion
        TextOutA(hdc, x, y, post.c_str(), post.size());

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, I really appreciate the code you've provided. I'm learning Windows but got some ways to go. Got my hands on "Windows 95 -Charles Petzold, and the Windows API Bible-James Conger".  So I started my journey. I actually got my Open file, Search file, display pop up pane, and editing to work to a degree. But trying to highlight words found eluded me. What kind of application I'm creating is still up in the air. Just happy that I got it going as well as I did. :)

Comment: @LoneWarriorForgottenTrails - those are great books for classic Win32 programming and still has some relevance today.  But you might want to consider a more modern UX framework such as UWP and/or XAML for building a modern windows app for Windows 10 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I created: [HighlightTextPainter](https://github.com/huxia1124/HighlightTextPainterSample)

Hopefully it's easier for you to use and understand.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32686445)